# How to test if a given path is a mount point (Windows)

Tags: python, windows

I'm looking for python code to test if given path is not on local drive (i.e. it's mounted) on Windows 10. If path is `K:\dir1\file2.txt` I want to know if it's local file or it's on network.
I checked internet and I found a solution for Posix only like `os.path.ismount(path)` but it doesn't work on Win10. It works only for `\\server\path`

I played w/ ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesA() (inspired here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/determining-whether-a-directory-is-a-volume-mount-point) but w/o good result.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `psutil`

Working method to get the `sdiskpart` information from your path

```
def find_mount_point(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    while not os.path.ismount(path):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
    p = [p for p in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True) if p.mountpoint == path.__str__()]
    l = len(p)
    if len(p) == 1:
        print type(p[0])
        return p[0]
    raise psutil.Error
```

If your drive is remote then

```
p = find_mount_point("X:")
print p.opts
```

should return

```
rw,remote
```

(see https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

To get the UNC from your drive lettre (knowing that it is **remote**) you can use `win32wnet`

```
import win32wnet
```

code to get diskpart (`p`)

```
print win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(p.mountpoint, 1)
```

Will print

```
\\My_Drive\my_folder
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed.